# Reading Json File in C# coming back null with no errors

Tags: c#, json, serialization, deserialization

Json File:

```json
{
  "ActionName": "JobGenertorTestActions",
  "ActionValue": "Test",
  "AppSource": "JobGeneratorApp",
  "AppText": "This is a test for a job generater app",
  "DetailName": "JobGenertorTestDetails",
  "DetailValue": "Test",
  "Filter": true,
  "FormID": "AccountingCheck",
  "UserID": 12345
}
```

```
string JobEditorPath = "C:/Git/JobGeneratorApp/JobGeneratorApp/JobEditor.json";
StreamReader JobEditorReader = new StreamReader(JobEditorPath);

    try
    {
        string jobEditorString = JobEditorReader.ReadToEnd();
        JobInfoLibrary JobEditor = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JobInfoLibrary>(jobEditorString);
        JobEditor.AppSource = JobInfo.AppSource;
        JobEditor.AppText = JobInfo.AppText;
        JobEditor.UserID = JobInfo.UserID;
        JobEditor.Filter = JobInfo.Filter;
        JobEditor.FormID = JobInfo.FormID;
        JobEditor.DetailName = JobInfo.DetailName;
        JobEditor.DetailValue = JobInfo.DetailValue;
        JobEditor.ActionName = JobInfo.ActionName;
        JobEditor.ActionValue = JobInfo.ActionValue;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex);
    }
```

[nulls in debug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8xwzA.png)

[json during runtime](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2hESG.png)

Comment: And your `JobInfoLibrary` class is?

Comment: Include your `JobInfoLibrary` class in the question

Comment: Probably something trivial like character casing or wrong root type

Comment: Also, why bother deserialziing if you then overwrite all the props?

Answer (score 0):

you have to swap your instances. You are trying to assign to already assigned

```
using (StreamReader JobEditorReader = new StreamReader(JobEditorPath))
{

 string json = JobEditorReader.ReadToEnd();
 JobInfoLibrary JobEditor = 
 JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JobInfoLibrary>(json);

 var JobInfo= new JobInfoLibrary();
 JobInfo.AppSource= JobEditor.AppSource;
... and so on
}
```

I only don know why you don't use JobInfo instead of JobEditor. You don't need both